# Microsoft Graph API: GET Outlook Calendar Event: Filter by Organizer Email

Tags: events, outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to GET Outlook Calendar event by organizer email.

Here is the request URL I'm using:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=organizer/emailAddress/address eq 'john@gmail.com'

The request fails with this error:

```
501 Not Implemented: {
 "error": {
 "code": "UnsupportedEntityExpression",
 "message": "'i => (i.Organizer.EmailAddress == \"john@gmail.com\")' is not a supported filter expression.",
 "innerError": {
 "request-id": "62206cba-ad9e-4051-b504-321cbcacc6fd",
 "date": "2017-08-04T23:39:47"
 }
 }
 }
```

FYI I'm running this request on an iPaas called Workato and this is the error message displayed on it.

What puzzles me is that this similar request works:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=organizer/emailAddress/name eq 'john doe'

Both name and address are properties of emailAddress so I'm not sure why the first request fails.

Has anyone filtered by organizer email before?

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce this error , and find a thread talking about same topic:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/426

It seems a bug and hasn't been fixed currently .